# Databricks dbutils throwing NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-keyvault, azure-databricks

Trying to read secret from Azure Key Vault using databricks dbutils, but facing the following exception:

```
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: eventLog.rolloverIntervalSeconds
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder$$anon$1.invoke(DBUtilsHolder.scala:17)
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
Object secret = DBUtilsHolder.dbutils().secrets().get("<scope>", "<key>");
System.out.println("secret " + secret.toString());
```

Below is the pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.airlift</groupId>
      <artifactId>airline</artifactId>
      <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.12</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/dbutils-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbutils-api_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

It failed when run from Databricks as spark-submit Job, but it worked when tried using Set Jar option.

Comment: what DBR version used?

Comment: @Alex DBR version is 6.4

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#create-a-job), Databricks Utilities are not available for spark-submit jobs. If you want to use Databricks Utilities, use JAR jobs instead.

Comment: While this is true, what is the alternative when requiring access to dbfs file systems running via spark-submit? ...or dbitils.secrets?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64757059/how-to-list-file-keys-in-databricks-dbfs-without-dbutils