# How to list file keys in Databricks dbfs **without** dbutils

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, filesystems, azure-databricks

Apparently [dbutils cannot be used in cmd-line spark-submits, you must use Jar Jobs for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242189/databricks-dbutils-throwing-nullpointerexception), but I MUST use spark-submit style jobs due to other requirements, yet still have a need to list and iterate over file keys in dbfs to make some decisions about which files to use as input to a process...

Using scala, what lib in spark or hadoop can I use to retrieve a list of `dbfs:/filekeys` of a particular pattern?

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

def ls(sparkSession: SparkSession, inputDir: String): Seq[String] = {
  println(s"FileUtils.ls path: $inputDir")
  val path = new Path(inputDir)
  val fs = path.getFileSystem(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  val fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(path)
  fileStatuses.filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath).map(_.getName).toSeq
}
```

Using the above, if I pass in a partial key prefix like `dbfs:/mnt/path/to/folder` while the following keys are present in said "folder":

- `/mnt/path/to/folder/file1.csv`
- `/mnt/path/to/folder/file2.csv`

I get `dbfs:/mnt/path/to/folder is not a directory` when it hits
`val path = new Path(inputDir)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use the SparkSession to do it.

Here's how we did it:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

def getFileSystem(sparkSession: SparkSession): FileSystem =
    FileSystem.get(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

def listContents(sparkSession: SparkSession, dir: String): Seq[String] = {
  getFileSystem(sparkSession).listStatus(new path(dir)).toSeq.map(_.getPath).map(_.getName)
}
```